# Loop and if statement do not give desired output

Tags: java

```
public class Shuffle1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;

        if(x > 2) {
            System.out.print("a");
        }

        while(x > 0) {
            x = x - 1;
            System.out.print("-");
        }

        if(x == 2) {
            System.out.print("b c");
        }

        if(x == 1) {
            System.out.print("d");
            x = x - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm learning Java from a book called "Head First Java", and I was using TextEdit as recommended in the book. I am supposed to be able to compile the code to get an answer of a-b c-d, but instead each time I compile it, I get a result of a---. I have checked it thoroughly myself and would really appreciate if anyone could help me. 
[Here is the original question from the book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmDrR.png)

Comment: I think the second and third `if` statements should be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger can really help debug your program. It will also help you be able to step through the code in your head with practice.

Answer (score 1):

So if `x` is 3, I'll take you through what happens:

1. Print's out "a" because 3 > 2
2. Decrements `x` to 0, printing "--" on the way because it took 2 decrements to satisfy break condition, x > 0

That means it would correctly print `a--`. To achieve `a-b c-d`, you must the if statements *inside* the loop, like this:

```
while(x > 0) {
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.print("-");

    if(x == 2) {
        System.out.print("b c");
    }

    if(x == 1) {
        System.out.print("d");
        x = x - 1;
    }
}
```

Now the execution cycle is:

1. `x` > 2, so print "a"
2. Goes into the loop
3. `x` becomes 2
4. Prints "-"
5. `x` is 2, so print "b c"
6. Continue iteration
7. Next iteration, `x` becomes 1
8. Print "-"
9. `x` is 1 so print "d"
10. `x` is now 0
11. Terminate loop

This gives the following desired result: `a-b c-d`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print as per your expectation.

```
public class Shuffle1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;    

        if(x > 2) {   //First time x=3, which is true
            System.out.print("a");  // print a
        }

        while(x > 0) {  // x=3, which is true
            x = x - 1;   //first loop, x=2, then second loop x=1
            System.out.print("-");  //prints "-"

          if(x == 2) {  // x=2, which is true
            System.out.print("b c"); //prints "b c"
             }

        if(x == 1) {  // as x=2, so it won't get display in first loop, but when it loop for second time, x become 1, which is true. 
            System.out.print("d");
            x = x - 1;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One moment please, I'm wrtiing..